# Modal with video

Tags: javascript, html, video, modal-dialog, frontend

I am trying to make modal with video that shows up after click on the button. When I try to put video from hard disc, the sound starts in the moment the website starts. Now, when I put video from youtube it is not working at all...
I have taken codes from different places, and put it together, cause I am beginner... Please help!

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
 
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <iframe width="640" height="480" controls="controls" type="video/mp4" autoplay="false" preload="none"><video width="1000" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOsGx25HvmI" frameborder="0"></video></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [YouTube support](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en):

> Embed a video
>
> 1. On a computer, go to the YouTube video you want to embed.
> 2. Under the video, click Share Share.
> 3. Click Embed.
> 4. From the box that appears, copy the HTML code.
> 5. Paste the code into your blog or website HTML.

You will note that the *URL* needs to be different. Instead of:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOsGx25HvmI
```

It will be:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/uOsGx25HvmI
```

The full code is:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uOsGx25HvmI" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Regarding the problem with the video playing sound on page load, you are trying to avoid `autoplay` doing `autoplay="false"`. From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-autoplay):

> To disable video autoplay, `autoplay="false"` will not work; the video will autoplay if the attribute is there in the `<video>` tag at all. To remove autoplay the attribute needs to be removed altogether.

Comment: Ok, it is working with youtube. But still, when I want to put to the code video from my computers hard disc, the sound starts even when I havent push the button. Only sound, video is playing normally after click on the button... :(

Comment: Do you think you can help me to write a simple modal - three columns, each contains picture. Clickin on them causes modal with text.
My js is not good, and for hours of trying I got exhausted :(